# How do you loop through an INI file using JS and/or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ini

I need help developing JS code (or PHP if it will be easier and more efficient) that can loop through INI comments, sections, settings and their values.

For example, this is my PHP:

```
<?php 
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini", true);
print_r(json_encode($ini_array));
?>
```

Here is the JSON that my PHP is outputting:

```
{"HEADINGONE":{"settingone":"hello","settingtwo":"world"},"HEADINGTWO":{"settingthree":"hi","settingfour":"again"}}
```

Which is parsing this INI file:

```
[HEADING ONE]
settingone=hello
settingtwo=world 

[HEADING TWO]
settingthree=hi
settingfour=again
```

And this is my JS:

```
$.getJSON('index.php', function (data) {
 $.each(data, function (i,item) {
  alert(i);
 });
});
```

So far my webpage alerts "HEADING ONE" and "HEADING TWO" but how can I get it to read the rest of the file?

So I can alert "HEADING ONE", "settingone", "hello", "HEADING TWO", and so forth.

Comment: Take a look at the output from the PHP page. Posting it here can help too.

Comment: you can inspect the JSON tree in browser console when you inspect request. According to php docs you will have nested array for each section by using `true` in `parse_ini_file`. Add another `each` inside the one you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('index.php', function (data) {
 $.each(data, function (i,item) {
   $.each(item, function (settingName, settingValue) {
      alert('setting: ' + settingName + ', value: ' + settingValue);
   });
 });
});
```

Comment: Although, your code was missing a closing parethesis, it did what I wanted, so thank you!

Comment: @StevenWaters you're right, I corrected the error (always hard editing code on stack overflow directly LOL